# Metamodel generator for any old class?

Tags: java, jpa, metamodel

I'm finding the JPA metamodel generator functionality really useful for avoiding bugs when column names change.  It would be really cool if there was some more general-purpose metamodel generation tool that you could point at any class (or a number of packages) that would generate similar metamodel classes.  This could then be used to create compile errors rather than runtime ones when things change:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public int somePublicProperty;

  public String someStringMethod() {
    ..
  }
}
```

This might create a metamodel class like:

```
public class SomeClass_ {
  public static final FieldAttribute<SomeClass,Integer> somePublicProperty;

  public static final MethodAttribute<SomeClass,String> somePublicMethod;
}
```

where FieldAttribute and MethodAttribute have useful Attribute-like methods to assist with reflection calls (i.e. remove the need to have bare strings):

```
Object someClassInstance = ... 
Integer value = SomeClass_.somePublicProperty.get( someClassInstance );

// rather than 
Integer value = someClassInstance.getClass().getDeclaredField( "somePublicProperty" ).get( someClassInstance );
```

Is there anything like this currently available?  There's a bit of support in Java 8 now we can do method references, but I'd like something a little bit more metamodel-like if it exists.

Comment: Eclipse Dali will generate the appropriate JPA metamodel classes dynamically, while you are editing your entities.

Comment: Hi Brian - I looked at Dali and it seems to only be for JPA classes.  I'm after a general-purpose metamodel generator that can be applied to *any* class, not just JPA @Entities.

Comment: Ahh - I apparently did not read closely enough. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this need a few times and I've implemented this:
https://github.com/mhagnumdw/bean-info-generator

**Below how you do use this**

If you're using Maven, add it to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.mhagnumdw</groupId>
    <artifactId>bean-info-generator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Annotate your class with @GenerateBeanMetaInfo

```
import io.github.mhagnumdw.beaninfogenerator.GenerateBeanMetaInfo;
@GenerateBeanMetaInfo
public class SomeClass {
    private int someProperty;
}
```

When the build run, SomeClass_INFO.java and SomeClass_INFO.class are generated

```
public abstract class SomeClass_INFO {
    public static final BeanMetaInfo someProperty = new BeanMetaInfo("someProperty");
}
```

Now you can do something like this

```
Field field = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredField(SomeClass_INFO.someProperty.getName());
```

Generate *_INFO.java at development time in Eclipse

- Right click on the project > Properties
- Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Factory path
- Add two jars: bean-info-generator-0.0.1.jar and javapoet-1.9.0.jar

I hope it helps!

Comment: This looks pretty close to exactly what I was looking for, thanks!